# Most of events has no any data (not set)

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using Google Analytics SDK in my app. SDK version is 3.13.0.

SDK is initialized properly without errors. Plist file is correct.

```
NSError *configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
```

All view controllers is `GAITrackedViewController` subclasses with names.

There is some events also:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];    
NSString* clientID = [tracker get:kGAIClientId];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:category
                                                      action:eventName
                                                       label:label
                                                       value:nil] build]];
```

My problem is most of events is "(not set)" - iOS version, session time, screen count, etc

[image]

[image]

I've found [bug report about similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35354035) however it's already fixed.

So I'm assuming that problem is on my side.
Actually I'm trying to change SDK version to latest (3.17.0)

Comment: Please show your code.  If its getting not set its probably because your not sending it.

Comment: @DaImTo my bad. Added.